# Impedance relay question

Tags: power

In the example below, I just don't understand why line 2–4 has a larger impedance than line 2–3?

[image]
[image]

[image]

SOURCE

Power System Analysis & Design,

Sixth Edition

J. Duncan Glover, Thomas J. Overbye, and Mulukutla S. Sarma

Copyright 2017 Cengage Learning.

ISBN: 978-1-305-63213-4

Comment: Why shouldn't it be like that?

Comment: @Andy aka Because it's the opposite, I mean 8 + j50 (Line 2-3) > 5.3 + j33 (Line 2-4). Right?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. Neither does it make sense to me.

Comment: @Andy aka Do you mean that what I wrote is wrong? Or that it's not clear?

Comment: I agree with you - it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Andy aka Sorry, sometimes the language difference confuses me. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't is just the definition of the given system, "what it is"? If those were the same, there is no need for sequencing.

Comment: I haven't done 3-phase stuff since college (more years than I wish to say), so take with a grain of salt....   But is it not true that Line 2-4 is 'open end' but line 2-3 has lines 1-2 and line 1-3 in parallel to it????    i.e. there's a 2nd current path so it has to be accounted for in the total impedance calculation.

Comment: Yes @KyleB , infeed effect.  Makes the fault look farther away.  Outfeed does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy commented, the lines are just different impedances (different construction, different lengths, or both).

I wanted to answer so I could point out some problems with the problem:

1. The given Z calculation uses phase to ground voltage divided by line current.  This is only true for a three phase fault.  If you have a mho distance relay the equations will be different for other fault types and the impedance seen by the relay based on the relay implementation (ground distance,  or phase distance, quads). e.g. \$Z=\frac{V_{AB}}{I_{AB}},Z=\frac{V_{BC}}{I_{BC}},   Z=\frac{V_{CA}}{I_{CA}}\$. For 3-phase fault these all measure same Z.
2. The problem ignores infeed from line 2-3 for faults down line 2-4.  If you don’t know what infeed or outfeed mean then you’re in a very basic class.
3. If station 2 uses breaker failure protection (which was not described in the problem) then this setting approach may be adequate (assumes breaker B23 open).
4. Impedance relays were early version relays that are rarely ever used anywhere anymore except legacy.  Proper terminology for modern phase fault relays is “distance relaying”.

Lotta good books out there, my favorite is [Lou Blackburn‘s](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439888116) book.  Here is [another great text](https://www.gegridsolutions.com/multilin/notes/artsci/artsci.pdf) by Mason that is free and covers infeed very well.

Lot of good tutorial papers on the IEEE PSRC website too - such as [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20220128033115/https://www.pes-psrc.org/kb/published/reports/D4_Application_of_Overreaching_Distance%20_Relays.pdf) and [this one.](https://web.archive.org/web/20220526172503/https://www.pes-psrc.org/kb/published/reports/DistanceElementResponse_FINAL_20130923.pdf)